# Are opening and closing double quotes expected to be of different color in a bash script?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, colorscheme, color, string-manipulation, default-settings

I've just noticed, after years using Vim, that the two double quote characters opening and closing a string in a bash script have different colors, which I can verify by simply writing `var="var"` in a shell script or opening up my `~/.bashrc`.

This seems to be independent of the colorscheme, and I can also reproduce it without my `.vimrc`, by opening

```
vi -u NONE ~/.bashrc
```

and then entering in Vim the following

```
:syntax enable
:colo pablo
```

(Those two colors are really different with `pablo`: yellow the opening double quote, blue-ish the closing one.)

I think that the answer to my question should be in `/usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/sh.vim` (which is sourced by the `bash.vim` in the same directory), but that file is a bit too complex for me to understand.

Here's a screencast
[image: asciicast]

In case it's relevant, this is the output of `vim --version`:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Aug 29 2020 00:50:37)
Included patches: 1-1523
Compiled by Arch Linux
Huge version with GTK3 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -farsi             +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary
+arabic            +file_in_path      -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
+autochdir         +float             +mouse_xterm       +tcl/dyn
-autoservername    +folding           +multi_byte        +termguicolors
+balloon_eval      -footer            +multi_lang        +terminal
+balloon_eval_term +fork()            -mzscheme          +terminfo
+browse            +gettext           +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
++builtin_terms    -hangul_input      +num64             +textobjects
+byte_offset       +iconv             +packages          +textprop
+channel           +insert_expand     +path_extra        +timers
+cindent           +ipv6              +perl/dyn          +title
+clientserver      +job               +persistent_undo   +toolbar
+clipboard         +jumplist          +popupwin          +user_commands
+cmdline_compl     +keymap            +postscript        +vartabs
+cmdline_hist      +lambda            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_info      +langmap           +profile           +virtualedit
+comments          +libcall           +python/dyn        +visual
+conceal           +linebreak         +python3/dyn       +visualextra
+cryptv            +lispindent        +quickfix          +viminfo
+cscope            +listcmds          +reltime           +vreplace
+cursorbind        +localmap          +rightleft         +wildignore
+cursorshape       +lua/dyn           +ruby/dyn          +wildmenu
+dialog_con_gui    +menu              +scrollbind        +windows
+diff              +mksession         +signs             +writebackup
+digraphs          +modify_fname      +smartindent       +X11
+dnd               +mouse             +sound             -xfontset
-ebcdic            +mouseshape        +spell             +xim
+emacs_tags        +mouse_dec         +startuptime       -xpm
+eval              +mouse_gpm         +statusline        +xsmp_interact
+ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      +xterm_clipboard
+extra_search      +mouse_netterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "/etc/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -pthread    -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fno-plt -D_REENTRANT  -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -fstack-protector-strong -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/5.32/core_perl/CORE  -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lz -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lharfbuzz -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0  -lSM -lICE -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm -ltinfo -lelf    -lcanberra  -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl   -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/5.32/core_perl/CORE -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/perl5/5.32/core_perl/CORE -lperl -lpthread -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc   -L/usr/lib -ltclstub8.6 -ldl -lz -lpthread -lm
```

Comment: Screenshot? I’ve never experienced that, and I write quite a bit of shell.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, updated with a screencast :)

Comment: I can reproduce that. Left quote is styled with `shQuote` while right one with `shSpecial`. The rule for a double quoted string (`shDoubleQuote`) sets `nextgroup=shSpecialStart` and I think this is what triggers that situation, but I can't tell whether this was intentional or not...

Comment: This seems to have been introduced in [version 190 of sh.vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/47e13953ffdbb9f163b901196dec8c2100b72edd#diff-3684eb3d10603a1e201bf60108720b02). DrChip has a more recent [version 193](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#SYNTAX_SH) on his website, maybe that fixes it? Otherwise, perhaps try a downgrade to 189?

Comment: Yeah this bug was introduced in 190 and was later fixed in 193... I'll post an answer.

Comment: I haven't repro'd this (though with my vimrc intact), even with v190

Comment: Wow. I wonder how we can verify if it is or isn't a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug was introduced on the Vim runtime update of May 12, 2020, with the [update of `syntax/sh.vim` from version 189 to version 190](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/47e13953ffdbb9f163b901196dec8c2100b72edd#diff-3684eb3d10603a1e201bf60108720b02) from April 14, 2020, which updated the `shDoubleQuoted` rule to include the part in bold below:

```
syn region  shDoubleQuote   matchgroup=shQuote start=+"+ matchgroup=shSpecial skip=+\\"+ end=+"+     contained   contains=@shDblQuoteList,shStringSpecial,@Spell nextgroup=shSpecialStart
```

This seems to have been fixed on the latest version by DrChip, who is the maintainer of this syntax file. In [version 193, the one currently available from his website](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#SYNTAX_SH), that line now also includes:

```
syn region  shDoubleQuote   matchgroup=shQuote start=+"+ matchgroup=shSpecial skip=+\\"+ matchgroup=shQuote end=+"+      contained   contains=@shDblQuoteList,shStringSpecial,@Spell nextgroup=shSpecialStart
```

You can upgrade your local installation to the latest version of Vim by downloading the `sh.vim.gz` file from DrChip's website, uncompressing it and saving it to `~/.vim/syntax/sh.vim` on your local machine, at least until the upstream Vim runtime catches up with the update that contains the fix for this issue. (You might want to consider updating your runtimes directly, expecting that your next Vim upgrade might already include this change.)

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a source repository or bug tracker where these changes can be tracked. But it seems to me that the intent of the initial change was to highlight a backslash-escaped sequence in a double quoted string using the `shSpecial` group, but in introducing this change it also affected the end match of the region (the closing double quote), which is what was then fixed with the second change, which resets the match group back to `shQuote` for the end pattern.

Comment: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/6416

Comment: Excellent answer accepted. Given your in this field, I guess you might also give a good answer at [this other question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61194384/is-this-change-to-vims-syntax-coloring-file-for-sed-good-or-disrupting).

Comment: I just ran "brew upgrade macvim" and it fixed it